# JQuery dialogs don't work after ajax partial view reload

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am manipulating a table of data in a View. When the user clicks on the data name, a dialog pops up to allow him to edit the data. When he clicks, delete, a dialog prompts him to make sure, then deletes the row. When he chooses to create new row, a dialog pops up to allow him to enter the new information. In all 3 cases, after the action is complete, the PartialView "_Content" reloads the content `<div />`.

This all works fine the first time, after the entire page loads. But after the PartialView reloads (after one of the actions), the "Edit" dialog no longer works, though the other 2 do. I can rig the page to reload everything after each action, of course, but that's slower and doesn't make sense in an Ajax world. If I put the JQueryUIHelper for the edit dialog in the partial view, again, it works the first time, but the second time, the form opens up inline on the page rather than in a dialog. I also tried this using JQuery and JQueryUI directly and got the same error. I have been researching this and experimenting for days.

**UPDATED 4/1/13:*** I added some `$.click()` callbacks to the link classes. They don't work after the page does the partial refresh. I guess what's happening is that the scripts lose their "connection" to the objects in the **content** `<div>` when the content reloads.

I am using MVC4, Razor, and JQueryUI via the JQueryUIHelper extension. The code for the View and PartialView is below.

Are there any ideas??

Here's my View

```
@model IEnumerable<AttributeLookup>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Attributes";
}
<h2>
Attributes</h2>
@if (ViewBag.Error != null)
{
<div class="message-error">@ViewBag.Error</div>
}
<div id="content">
   @Html.Partial("_Content", Model)
</div>

<div style="padding-top: 12px;">
@Ajax.ActionLink("New", "Create", new { }, new AjaxOptions {
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "createContent"
}, new { id = "createLink" })
</div>

@using (Html.JQueryUI().Begin(new Dialog()
.Title("Confirm Delete")
.AutoOpen(false)
.Modal(true)
.CloseOnEscape(true)
.ConfirmAjax(".deleteLink", "Yes", "No",
new AjaxSettings { Method = HttpVerbs.Post, Success = "content" })))
{
<div>
    Are you sure you want to delete this attribute?
</div>
}
@using (Html.JQueryUI().Begin(new Dialog()
.Title("Create Attribute")
.AutoOpen(false)
.Width(500)
.TriggerClick("#createLink")
.Modal(true)
.CloseOnEscape(true)
.Button("OK", "save")
.Button("Cancel", "closeDialog")))
{
<div id="createContent" />
}
@using (Html.JQueryUI().Begin(new Dialog(new {id = "editDialog"})
.Title("Edit Attribute")
.AutoOpen(false)
.Width(500)
.TriggerClick(".editLink")
.Modal(true)
.CloseOnEscape(true)
.Button("OK", "save")
.Button("Cancel", "closeDialog")))
{
<div id="editContent" />
}

@section Scripts {
   <script type="text/javascript">

  var success = function(data) {
     $(window.document.body).html(data);
  };

  var content = function(data) {
     $("#content").html(data);
  };

  var closeDialog = function() {
     $(this).dialog('close');
  };

      var saveCreate = function() {
         $("#createForm").submit();
         $(this).dialog('close');
      };

      var saveEdit = function() {
         $("#editForm").submit();
         $(this).dialog('close');
      };

      $(".editLink").click(function () { alert("edit clicked"); });
      $(".deleteLink").click(function () { alert("delete clicked"); });

   </script>
}
```

Here's the PartialView

```
@model IEnumerable<AttributeLookup>
@if (ViewBag.Error != null)
{
<div class="message-error">@ViewBag.Error</div>
}
<table id="attribute">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th style="width: 250px;">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th style="width: 50px;">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Units)
    </th>
    <th style="width: 30px;">
        Contrained
    </th>
    <th style="width: 400px;">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th>
        &#160;
    </th>
    </tr>
    @{ int count = 0; }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    string type = count % 2 == 0 ? "normal" : "alt";
    <tr class="@type">
        <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name).ToHtmlString(), "Edit",
        new { id = item.AttributeLookupID }, new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "Get",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "editContent"
        }, new { @class = "editLink", title = "Edit attribute" })
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Units)
        </td>
        <td>
        @if (item.AttributeConstraints != null && item.AttributeConstraints.Any())
        {
            @Html.Raw("X")
        }
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.AttributeLookupID }, new { @class = "deleteLink" })
        </td>
    </tr>
        count++;
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the Partial for the Edit form. The Create form is similar:

```
@model AttributeLookup
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "AttributeLookup", new AjaxOptions {
HttpMethod = "Post",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "content"
}, new {id = "editForm"}))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>AttributeLookup</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AttributeLookupID)
    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Units)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Units)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Units)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttributeConstraints, "Constraint")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("ConstraintTypeID")
    @Html.DropDownList("SecondaryID")
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Some more evidence: I've added these lines to the `<script>` section: 
`$(".editLink").click(function () { alert("edit clicked"); });`
`$(".deleteLink").click(function () { alert("delete clicked"); });`
Both alerts work before the Partial refresh. Neither do afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. First, I removed the TriggerClick from the Helper:

```
@using (Html.JQueryUI().Begin(new Dialog(new {@id = "editDialog"})
    .Title("Edit Attribute")
    .AutoOpen(false)
    .Width(500)
    // deleted --> .TriggerClick(".editLink")
    .Modal(true)
    .CloseOnEscape(true)
    .Button("OK", "saveEdit")
    .Button("Cancel", "closeDialog")))
{
    <div id="editContent" />
}
```

And then I explicitly added it to my `<scripts>`:

```
$("body").on('click', ".editLink", function () { $("#editDialog").dialog("open"); });
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why it works for the other two, but not the edit one? I suspect it has to to with mistakes startingfrom the id. Try taking away id=editdialog. This might be a quickfix. If this doesnt work, keep reading.

The #dialog usually hides due to jqueryUi things that go on at document.ready or page load in the background.

I'm not sure exaclty when it happens, but you'd want to repeat those steps after the reload happens.
At the end of the document in a part thats not reloaded do something like...

```
  <script>
   $("body").ajaxComplete( reHideDialog())

     function reHideDialog(){
            $("#dialog").css('display','none');
     }
 </script>
```

when they click the edit link, jqueryui should automatically set the #dialog css display to display:absolute as it renders it in a popup.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, @user1778606. They don't seem to be doing the trick, however. I will continue to chase down this path, though.